# how rails default cache works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, token

I have an app used by a certain number of users. At some point of the application, I do this

```
Rails.cache.write('token', ['token'])
```

and on another, I read it by `Rails.cache.read('token')`. But I was wondering: is the `Rails.cache` a global thing? I mean, will the users access the same token. Let's say User A logs, and his token is saved, then User B logs, his token is saved in the same way. On future actions, will User A access the token written by User B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the cache is global even for different users. There is [a guide about caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

There is a reason behind it. Cache is actually designed for the application to respond quicker to similar queries issued even by different users. Typically a fragment (or even an entire page) is rendered after it's been changed (through che "cache invalidation" mechanism) and then afterwards only the already rendered object is served from the cache.

For example, this works exceptionally well on a news website, where a page with an article is rendered only for the first reader, and further renders bypass page generation and serve the already rendered page right from the cache, greatly increasing the number of readers the server can withstand (as opposed to generation of the page on every request).

Same cache keys will always point to the same data (if it doesn't change) for any users if there is only one cache service. If there are multiple (say, if multiple app instances are running on the same DB with a load balancer), results **should** still be the same if the app is designed properly.

Any user-specific stuff can only be stored in a **session** or a **cookie** (I've even seen cookie-based sessions).

Comment: Thanks! I was suspecting this ahahah